# Появление меню по width при клике

Tags: jquery

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось меню (появление по width, как бы от 0 до 280Px)

```
<div class="container uk-margin-remove">

        <button type="button" class="menu-for-phone">Тыкни и вылезет менюшка</button>

        <div class="dropdown-left-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 10</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Стили:

```
.dropdown-left-menu {
    /* top: 0; */
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}

.dropdown-left-menu ul {
    padding: 10px 0 0 30px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать с помощью встроенных функций jquery:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.dropdown-left-menu').hide();

$('.menu-for-phone').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown-left-menu').toggle('slide');
});
```

});

Но здесь возникает проблема, что меню изменяется и по ширине и по высоте.

Есть ли какие-то методы для появления менюшки по ширине?

И необходимо еще реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на пространство вне меню, оно скрывалось также по ширине.

```
$(this).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
        var leftMenu = $(".dropdown-left-menu"); // тут указываем ID элемента
        if (!leftMenu.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
            && leftMenu.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
            leftMenu.slideDown(400);
        }
    });
```

Делал так, но тоже не то, что нужно..

Comment: $('.dropdown-left-menu').css({
  width: '0',
  opacity: '0'
 });

 $('.menu-for-phone').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown-left-menu').animate({'width': '280px', 'opacity': '1'}, 1000);
 });  еще есть такой вариант с помощью animate, но тогда текст сначала съезжает, потом встает на месте..

Comment: "Но здесь возникает проблема, что меню изменяется и по ширине и по высоте" - так вы же сами пишите .slideDown().

Comment: @Gonzo да, я уже понял. Написал функцию animate, все работает, но текст съезжает при начале анимации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так.

```js
$('.menu-for-phone').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown-left-menu').toggleClass('dropdown-left-menu_opened');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-left-menu {
    /* top: 0; */
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 1s ease;
}

.dropdown-left-menu ul {
    padding: 10px 0 0 30px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 280px;
}


.dropdown-left-menu_opened {
  width: 280px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container uk-margin-remove">

        <button type="button" class="menu-for-phone">Тыкни и вылезет менюшка</button>

        <div class="dropdown-left-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Пункт 10</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Действительно, так работает. Но текст съезжает при начале анимации (если поставить transition 1s)

Comment: Хотя, думаю, такая slow анимация будет излишне. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: На будущее просто хотелось бы знать, как реализовать такой момент с съезжанием текста

Comment: Ну я поставил там 1s, вроде не съезжает. Чтобы текст не дергался я специально задал фиксированную ширину внутренней части меню (самому списку). Так же можно для блоков с текстом для которых не допустим переход на другую строку при раскрытии ставит white-space: nowrap;

Comment: Не совсем понятно что имеется ввиду под съезжающим текстом.

Comment: Цифры съезжают на следующую строку при раскрытии

Comment: вылечить можно либо фиксированной шириной внутренней части, либо свойством white-space, запретив перевод на другую строку, но это нужно будет делать для самих элементов li, или ссылок внутри них

Comment: Спасибо, white-space: nowrap; помог!

Comment: А вот такой вопрос, как скрыть это меню при клике вне области?

Comment: Дело в том, что кнопка вызова меню - это тоже "вне области" меню. Так что если делать вашим способом то нужно будет учесть еще и это. Иначе при попытке вызова меню оно сразу будет скрываться.

Comment: Ааа, да, логично. Этот момент не учел

Comment: Я в таких случаях обычно делаю большой блок с position: fixed (меню кстати тоже fixed, а не absolute) на всю высоту/ширину страницы под меню, и делаю ему z-index меньше чем у меню. Этот блок по дефолту скрыт, но при клике на меню он становится видимым. В этом случае вместо клика "вне области" меню можно отслеживать клик по нему

Comment: Хорошее решение. Попробую такой способ